# which functions done/next are bound to in mongoos pre/save/(serial/parallel) middleware

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Trying to understand mongoose middleware (pre/save/parallel) thru docs/blogs(Tim Casewell).

Based on http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

```
var schema = new Schema(..);
schema.pre('save', true, function (next, done) {
  // calling next kicks off the next middleware in parallel
  next();
  doAsync(done);
});

The hooked method, in this case save, will not be executed until done is called by each middleware.
```

***What is done/next bound to here? Can you please give a complete example of how to use it?***

For eg: I use serial as follows:

```
myModel.save(function(err) {
  if (err) 
    console.error("Error Occured")
  else
    console.info("Document Stored");
});

Schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (!self.validateSomething()) {
    next(new Error());
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

*What is next bound to here? It needs to be bound to something to get executed? I fail to understand which function(s) next/done are referring to?*

***If you could elaborate control flow for my code above, that would be a great help.***

-------------**This is just to elaborate my understanding (not part of question)**------

```
   * On executing myModel.save(...)
   * Control Flow will be passed to pre/save
   * if self.validateSomething() fails,
     * Document will not be tried to be saved in DB
     * "Error Occurred" will be printed on console
   * if validation succeeds,
     * Control Flow should be passed to *somewhere* in Mongoose libs 
       * Document will be tried to save in DB
         * On Success, "Document saved" will be printed on the console
         * On Failure, "Error Occurred" will be printed on console
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're bound to functions that provide flow control internally within Mongoose.  Mongoose depends on [hooks-js](https://github.com/bnoguchi/hooks-js) for its middleware functionality, see the source for more details.

For example, if you have multiple pre-save middleware functions, `next` will call a function that will call the next pre-save middleware or on error, will pass the error back to your `save` callback.

Using `done` is a more advanced option for flow control, allowing multiple pre-save, for example, middleware to execute at once, but not moving past the pre-save step until `done` has been called in all middleware functions.

Comment: thanks. Based on some keywords in your reply, I was able to find https://github.com/bnoguchi/hooks-js which clears up lots of things. I will accept your answer soon.

Comment: Ah, cool.  I didn't realize that mongoose used a dependency for middleware.  That's pretty handy actually.